# MPMusicPlaybackState Button Title Not Changing

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have just successfully set up somewhat of a music player. It queries the user's iTunes and plays songs based on the query. For some reason, the button, won't change when the Playback state changes. I have both and NSLog and Label and they both reference it but when it comes to the button, nothing happens. Here's the code:

```
- (void) handle_PlaybackStateChanged: (id) notification {

MPMusicPlaybackState playbackState = [self.player playbackState];


if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused) {

    self.textLabel.text = @"play";
    [PlayButton setTitle:@"STOP" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // To set the title

    NSLog (@"This is paused");
    self.playBarButton.title = @"Play";

     self.PlayButton = PlayButton;


    [self.PlayButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor]      forState:UIControlStateNormal];


   } else if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {

    self.textLabel.text = @"pause";
    [PlayButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.PlayButton = PauseButton;
    NSLog (@"This is playing");



} else if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped) {

    self.textLabel.text = @"Play";
    self.PlayButton = PlayButton;


    [self.player stop];

}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which is actually your button self.player,self.PlayButton or PlayButton. Please post where are you initializing the button.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. It is linked from the .h | @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* PlayButton;

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I just needed to add the code below in viewDidLoad

```
if ([musicPlayer playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {

[playPauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pauseButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

} else {

[playPauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```